# ValueError with union of two arrays using the OR operator

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using Python and numpy where I have a couple of numpy arrays of the same shape and I am trying to create a union of these arrays. these arrays contain only 0 and 1 and basically I want to merge them into a new array using the OR operation. So, I do the following:

```
import numpy as np

segs = list()
a = np.ones((10, 10)).astype('uint8')
b = np.zeros((10, 10)).astype('uint8')
segs.append(a)
segs.append(b)

mask = np.asarray([any(tup) for tup in zip(*segs)]).astype('uint8')
```

With the last staement I get the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

If I use `np.any`, somehow my array shape is now just `(10,)`. How can I create this merge without explicitly looping through the arrays?

**EDIT**

```
mask = np.asarray([any(tup) for tup in zip(segs)]).astype('uint8')
```

also results in the same error.

Comment: How about `a | b`?

Comment: yes, but I could in theory have many arrays. I did this  to create a simple reproducible program. The size may also only be known during runtime

Comment: Then how about `np.logical_or.reduce((a, b))`? Your current code is calling `any` on a tuple of two NumPy arrays in each iteration, which evidently won't work.

Comment: Ahhhh...that works! Do you want to write it as an answer?

Comment: Python logical operators don't work well with numpy arrays (`if`, `or`, `any` etc).  Numpy ones like `|`, `np.any` are better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `segs` is a list of 2 arrays:

```
In [25]: segs = [np.ones((3,6),'uint8'), np.zeros((3,6),'uint8')]
In [26]: [tup for tup in zip(*segs)]
Out[26]: 
[(array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8),
  array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)),
 (array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8),
  array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)),
 (array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8),
  array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8))]
```

The `zip` produces tuples of 1d arrays (pairing rows of the two arrays).  Python `any` applied to arrays gives the ambiguity error - that's true for other logical Python operations like `if`, `or`, etc, which expect a scalar `True/False`.

You tried `np.any` - that turns the tuple of arrays into a 2d array.  But without an `axis` parameter it works on the flattened version, return a scalar `True/False`.  But with an axis parameter we can apply this `any` across rows:

```
In [27]: [np.any(tup, axis=0) for tup in zip(*segs)]
Out[27]: 
[array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]),
 array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]),
 array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])]
```

Using the `logical_or` ufunc as suggested in a comment:

```
In [31]: np.logical_or(segs[0],segs[1])
Out[31]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
In [32]: np.logical_or.reduce(segs)
Out[32]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Using the '|' operator isn't quite the same:

```
In [33]: segs[0] | segs[1]
Out[33]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

It uses the `segs[0].__or__(segs[1])` method.  I'd have to check the docs to see what is going on.  Application to `uint8` (or other numeric values) is different from application to `bool`.  Almost looks like a `max`.